# Why Modification Indices CheckBox unable to check?

Tags: amos

I want to do a 2 order CFA with AMOS. My data set does not contain any missing values. When I try to run the model, it says "The model is probably unidentified....".

So I tried to increase the modification level by checking the modification indices checkbox.

After I checked it and run again, it gives me the following error.

**Error ScreenShot:**

[image]

[image]

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: One of the arrows from SEi should have the regression weight 1. Did you assign that and try?

Comment: I found the issue, it was because of my data set contain 2 Null values. When I clean those, issue got resolved. Thank you